# How to use curl to get data instead of website?

Tags: curl, nginx, redis, get, openresty

I have this code which supposedly gets a redis key value from the url:

```
location /getkey/(^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]*)$ {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
            content_by_lua_block {
                local redis = require "resty.redis"
                local red = redis:new()

                red:set_timeout(1000) -- 1 sec

                -- or connect to a unix domain socket file listened
                -- by a redis server:
                --     local ok, err = red:connect("unix:/path/to/redis.sock")

                local ok, err = red:connect("127.0.0.1", 6379)
                if not ok then
                    ngx.say("failed to connect: ", err)
                    return
                end


                ngx.say("set result: ", ok)
                ngx.say("Getting $1")
                local res, err = red:get("$1")
                if not res then
                    ngx.say("failed to get $1: ", err)
                    return
                end

                if res == ngx.null then
                    ngx.say("$1 not found.")
                    return
                end

                ngx.say(res)
    }
}
```

Currently I'm using this curl command to GET the data response:

`curl -X GET http://localhost/getkey/insertkeyhere`

However I'm getting a html instead:

```
<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>openresty/1.13.6.2</center>
</body>
</html>
```

In my log, it shows the directory/location is not found:

```
2018/07/17 13:38:17 [error] 18425#18425: *179 open() "/usr/local/openresty/nginx/html/getkey/hello2" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /getkey/hello2 HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
```